# AJAX:How can I redirect page and then refresh once

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#postform").live("submit",function(){
        var datastring=$(this).serialize();
    var postid=$(this).("post_id").serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "post_edit_save.php",
          data:  datastring,
          cache   : false,
          success: function(html){
            window.location.href='post_info.php?post_id='+postid;
          }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I use this code with ajax to redirect from page A. to page B. after edit data(like edit post in forum).
but when page B finish loading,Page B apear a old data before i edit it (old post) i've to refresh it once to make new data appear.

How can i make Page B appear a new data right after redirect from page A without refresh.

Comment: You'll need to show us more code - especially the **entire** `$.ajax` call.

Comment: If the browser is caching page B, you could get around this by adding something like `&cachebuster=' + Math.random` to your query string.

Comment: @sberry You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Unrelated: `.live()` is deprecated (removed in jQuery 1.9), you should use `.on()` instead.

Comment: @sberry YES! That's answer

Answer (score 0):

Code is working, it look like browser caching problem. you can add meta tag in `<head>` tag

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

or you can add randome query string in url as some one suggested in comment.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not load anything new since you are probably setting `location.href` equal to the current location.

If you are already at `post_info.php?post_id=123` and you set `location.href` to the same address then nothing will happen. The page will not be loaded.

So this is not a cache issue. Instead you should invoke

```
location.reload();
```

...in your success callback.

That will reload the page and display the new data.